# Need to loop command when container starts

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I'm trying to start a container with [Seq log](https://datalust.co/seq), but i want to start it already with a api-key setted. So, i've tried to use another container to use a command line:

```
version: '3.7'

services:
  logseqcli:
    image: datalust/seqcli:5.1.251
    command: apikey create --title='newapikey' --token='123456' --server=http://logseq
    depends_on:
      - logseq
  logseq:
    image: datalust/seq:5.1
    environment:
      - ACCEPT_EULA=Y
    ports:
      - 2000:80
      - 4000:5341
```

I'm receiving a "Connection refused" message error from *logseqcli* container; Seq support told me this was because *logseqcli* executed the command before *logseq* container had fully started, so sugested me to create a loop to execute the command. I've tried this:

```
logseqcli:
    image: datalust/seqcli:5.1.251
    command: >
      /bin/bash -c "
        seqcli apikey create --title='newapikey' --token='123456' --server=http://logseq;
        while $$? != 0;
        do
          seqcli apikey create --title='newapikey' --token='123456' --server=http://logseq;
          sleep 1;
        done;"
    depends_on:
      - logseq
```

But with this the command isn't even identified. There's a properly way to loop a command on a container with docker-compose?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you cant use `/bin/bash`  command without overwriting the docker entry point. Here is one way to fix it

docker-compose

```
version: '3.7'

services:
  logseqcli:
    build: .
    depends_on:
      - logseq
  logseq:
    image: datalust/seq:5.1
    environment:
      - ACCEPT_EULA=Y
    ports:
      - 2000:80
      - 4000:5341
```

entry_point

```
#!/bin/bash -e

SERVICE="http://logseq"

until curl -fs $SERVICE  > /dev/null; do
  >&2 echo "$SERVICE is unavailable - sleeping"
  sleep 2
done
>&2 echo "$SERVICE is up"

exec /bin/seqcli/seqcli apikey create --title='newapikey' --token='1kjdhfsdldkfa093482092823456' --server=$SERVICE

exit 0
```

dockerfile

```
FROM datalust/seqcli:5.1.251

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y curl

COPY ./docker-entrypoint.sh /
ENTRYPOINT ["/docker-entrypoint.sh"]
```

Comment: Thanks, it realy makes sense. But i'm gettint a error inside bash: 
`docker-entrypoint.sh: Syntax error: end of file unexpected (expecting "do")` Do you know whats wrong with the shell script?

Comment: did you have the full entry point? what is the content of the file inside the docker container?

Comment: It was a syntax error, now the loop works; its shows twice the "service is unavailable" message, and after that it shows the "service is up" message, and then, shows "/docker-entrypoint.sh: 16: /docker-entrypoint.sh: seqcli: Permission denied". It happens even if i set the bash command to "seqcli help" only. I need to set some kind of permission on the shell script?

Comment: you need to use bash for the entry point and use a long token